# Cost and ease of getting visas for China in Hong Kong for US Citizens

Tags: visas, us-citizens, china, hong-kong

I lived in mainland China as an English teacher from August 2006 to August 2008.  At that time, it was pretty easy for a US citizen to obtain a Chinese tourist visa in Hong Kong (I myself got a tourist visa to re-enter China for the Beijing Olympics after my residence permit expired).  I haven't been back to China since leaving in August 2008 and am now planning a trip with the family (myself, my wife, and three children) for Summer 2017.

I know that you can get multiple-entry visas at a Chinese Embassy in the US that are good for ten years but they are quite expensive, particularly for a family of five, and we really don't need a 10-year visa.  Given that we'll be traveling in Asia for a couple of months this summer (I've got a ten week sabbatical!) and will likely be visiting Hong Kong for a few days anyway, I'm considering waiting to get our visas until we are there.

Is it still easy to get a visa in Hong Kong?

How much does it cost and how long is it good for?

Comment: The answers on the question this is a duplicate of do not answer the pricing part of the question.